# get_template_part appears to be removing a class on h2

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a custom template part that includes an h2 with the classes "sectionmarker" and "bodycontent", like this:

```
<h2 class="sectionmarker bodycontent">Title</h2>
```

When I call get_template_part() on a page, the output I'm getting is:

```
<h2 class="bodycontent">Title</h2>
```

For some reason, it seems not to like "sectionmarker". I even switched the order of the two classes, like this:

```
<h2 class="bodycontent sectionmarker">Title</h2>
```

And I get the same output with only the bodycontent class applied. What's going on here?

Full template content:

```
<?php
$abstract=get_post_field('post_content',224);
  $news=get_posts(array(
    'post_type'=> 'news'
  ));

  $newsdata=array();
  foreach ($news as $n) {
    $item=new stdClass();
    $item->title=get_the_title($n->ID);
    $item->date=get_the_date("",$n->ID);
    $item->content=get_field('more_info',$n->ID);
    array_push($newsdata,$item);
  }

  $newsdata_json=json_encode($newsdata);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(<?php echo $newsdata_json ?>);
</script>

<?php
  echo $abstract;
  if(count($newsdata)>0){
?>
  <h2 class="sectionmarker bodycontent" >News</h2>
    <?php foreach ($newsdata as $newsitem) { ?>
      <h4 class='datemarker bodycontent'><?php echo $newsitem->date ?></h4>
      <p class='newstext bodycontent'><?php echo $newsitem->title ?></p>

<?php } } ?>
```

and here's the call I'm making (in home.php):

```
get_template_part('custom-home-template',null,array());
```

Comment: That's unlikely. You're probably either fetching the wrong template, check the handle. Can you add the full content from the template and also the file it's being called from

Comment: It's definitely the right template — I can make edits to other parts of the template, and they update immediately. I added the full content though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! I just remembered I have some JavaScript that's changing the h2 classes on load.